# Find duplicates between 2 SQL Server tables and return both values in another table and update as duplicate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 SQL Server tables. Table #1 is `tblHistory`, the second is `tblTemp`, where a daily Excel is uploaded into, and #3 is `tblDuplicate`.

Sample data:

**tblHistory**:

```
PostingDate  DocumentDate Reference URN   Supplier  St   Check1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-11-05    12/09/2018   12345    12345   12345    2   12/09/201812345
```

**tblTemp**:

```
PostingDate  DocumentDate Reference URN   Supplier  St   Check1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-10-05    12/09/2018   12345    12345   12345    2   12/09/201812345
```

I have written a query to return the duplicate values

```
select 
    PostingDate, DocumentDate, Reference, URN, St, Check1 
from 
    tblTemp
where 
    Check1 in (select Check1 from tblHistory);
```

but so far it is returning only one value.

I also need the query to return both values in `tblDuplicate`.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you expand more? It will only return 1 value if there is only 1 value in the table. See if you can put more values in the sample data.

Comment: Do you mean you need to return the values from the temp and the one from the history in the same query?

Comment: with a simple Inner Join usage you can return values only existing in target table

Comment: You could use [INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) here, I believe. `SELECT * FROM tblHistory INTERSECT SELECT * FROM tblTemp`

Comment: any idea on how i can export the results to another table please. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tblDuplicate
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN, h.St, h.Check1 
      FROM tblHistory h
      WHERE h.Check1 IN(SELECT Check1 FROM tblTemp)
    UNION 
      SELECT t.PostingDate, t.DocumentDate, t.Reference, t.URN, t.St, t.Check1 
      FROM tblTemp t
      WHERE t.Check1 IN(SELECT Check1 FROM tblHistory)
    ) as AllData
```

With this request you return all data in tblTemp and tblHistory if data in the other table.

Comment: the above query is working fine. the target table is tblDuplicate. How can I export the results to tblDuplicate Please.

Comment: You Just add INSERT INTO with your table reference.

Comment: just what i needed. Thank you Samuel.

Comment: any idea why i am getting the following error message "Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
"

Comment: because its not the same column in table you need define after INSERT INTO tblDuplicate (column1, column2, column3)